# meteor server startup error with balanced-payments package

Tags: meteor, balanced-payments

### **ORIGINAL QUESTION -- HAS BEEN FIXED (see below)**

I'm new to meteor and trying to use the meteor-balanced-payments package by Ian Serlin (https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-balanced-payments).  The package appears properly installed, yet I'm having problems on both the client and server side just to properly load the package to start using it.  I could use a complete running example if anyone has one.

The client side looks like the underscore builtin package is being loaded after the session-extras package that meteor-balanced-payments advocates for using.  Note that `Meteor.settings.public.balanced.marketplaceUri` is set correctly to my test marketplace Uri string of the form `/v1/marketplaces/TEST-########################`.  The client init code is:

[client/main.js]:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Session.whenTrue("balancedLoaded", function() {
    balanced.init(Meteor.settings.public.balanced.marketplaceUri);      
  });
});
```

When run the following errors appear in the Chrome javascript console.  The first line of session-extras.js is `"_.extend(Session,{"`, which means the problem is the first `"_"` underscore use.  Any suggestions what to do?  Don't the packages make the dependencies explicit?  I'm not sure what to do to correct.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined session-extras.js:1
>   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'whenTrue'

The second problem is the server side fails claiming that nbalanced does not exist.  The code for the server and the corresponding console errors are as follows.  This looks to be just how the meteor-balanced-payments package docs suggest it to be done.  nbalanced is in the smart package as a Npm dependency that gets built as part of the package.  Any suggestions why `nbalanced` is not defined?

[server/bootstrap.js]:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  balanced = new nbalanced({
    secret: Meteor.settings.balanced.apiSecret,
    marketplace_uri: Meteor.settings.balanced.marketplaceUri
  });
});
```

console output:

```
2042-01:58:33.453(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/foo/test-payments4/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:185
W2042-01:58:33.454(-4)? (STDERR) }).run();
W2042-01:58:33.454(-4)? (STDERR)    ^
W2042-01:58:33.456(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: nbalanced is not defined
W2042-01:58:33.457(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/bootstrap.js:12:18
W2042-01:58:33.457(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/foo/test-payments4/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:158:61
W2042-01:58:33.457(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W2042-01:58:33.457(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/foo/.meteor/tools/a80b2d5689/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W2042-01:58:33.458(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/foo/test-payments4/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:158:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Other relevant files ...

[smart.json]:

```
{
  "packages": {
        "balanced-payments": {},
        "session-extras": {},
        "sync-methods": {}
  }
}
```

[smart.lock]:

```
{
  "meteor": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "basePackages": {
      "balanced-payments": {},
      "session-extras": {},
      "sync-methods": {}
    },
    "packages": {
      "balanced-payments": {
        "git": "https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-balanced-payments.git",
        "tag": "v0.1.1",
        "commit": "6ebc8f9855f35c040b67f0d9bebf16870160c1b2"
      },
      "session-extras": {
        "git": "https://github.com/belisarius222/meteor-session-extras.git",
        "tag": "v0.3.0",
        "commit": "0c49d41009821e76f46af3ad65d0a1d5bfa8d4eb"
      },
      "sync-methods": {
        "git": "https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-sync-methods.git",
        "tag": "v0.1.1",
        "commit": "2a7b094d54f3fb7c9acebbe10b68f9db1e5f156b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Relevant version numbers:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin mini-en0.home 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ node --version
v0.10.19

$ mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.6.14
```

### **SOLUTION**

The problem is that both of these packages (balanced-payments and session-extras) have not been updated for the 0.6.5 namespace changes.  I made the following changes to a local copy of the packages to get them to work.  Now it runs cleanly.

[balanced-payments/package.js]:  Needs to export the nbalanced symbol with api.export() so the server can use it ...

```
Package.describe({
    summary: 'Balanced Payments (nbalanced packaged for meteor)'
});

Npm.depends({
    'nbalanced': 'https://github.com/ianserlin/nbalanced/tarball/05eb18cf3536e22b62f349d0520e5df23740dd5c'
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use('sync-methods', 'server');

    api.add_files('index.js', 'server');
    api.add_files('balanced.js', 'client');

    api.export('nbalanced', 'server');
});
```

[session-extras/package.js]:  Needs to import underscore and session via api.use() so that Session can be extended ...

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "a few useful helpers for Meteor's Session"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use('underscore', 'client');
    api.use('session', 'client');

    api.add_files([
        'session-extras.js'
    ],'client');
});
```

Comment: Do you try upgrading meteor to 0.6.6.1 to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm running the latest meteor.

$ meteor --version
Release 0.6.6.1

Comment: Your error may start form session-extra. I encounter the same undefined error when using Smart Collection.